# Dual arm UR10 connection with universal robot stack

Tags: ros, ur10, universal-robots

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,

I'm working with two ur10 arms. i can easily set up a connection with the universal robot stack from github using the driver.py with one robot arm. I'm using the ipa320 fork (github.com/ipa320/universal_robot) with groovy.

I'm sure both arms are reachable over the network and i can set up a connection with each arm individually.

My problem is when i wont to establish the connections simultaniously.. when i'm connecting to the second ur10 the connection attempt fails. I'm not really familliar wit tcp and sockets but in my opinion the connection fails cause the ur10 box trys to establish the connection only through port 500001. I know that this python scripts tells the ur10 box to setup a connection. But i dont't know how to tell the box over whitch port the connection should be established. In the driver.py is a variable define REVERSE_PORT = 50001 but it is not used in the code. Does somebody has deeper insights in the connection process or already accomplished to set up a connection with two ur10's and moveit?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Matthias.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/129911/dual-arm-ur10-connection-with-universal-robot-stack/) by [Equanox](https://answers.ros.org/users/8566/equanox/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2014-02-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-02-17**:
Is this with a single or dual controller setup?

**Comment by [Equanox](https://answers.ros.org/users/8566/equanox/) on 2014-02-18**:
dual controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

All right,

I found the answer. Thers a file named "prog" in the ur_driver package. You can change the port for the connection between arm and pc in line 116, with the second argument of the command socket_open(HOSTNAME, 50001). You also need to change the port in line 642 in the driver.py.

Right now there is no solution added for doing this during runtime.

Cheers,
Matthias

---

Originally posted by [Equanox](https://answers.ros.org/users/8566/equanox/) with karma: 36 on 2014-02-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-04-16**:
See also https://github.com/ros-industrial/universal_robot/issues/39 for a discussion about this.

**Comment by [yyf](https://answers.ros.org/users/29997/yyf/) on 2017-08-17**:
I meet a strange problem.I want to setup a connection between PC and two UR5 arms , but the topic "follow joint tracjetory" cannot be created.The error displayed is "Action client not connected:left_arm_controller/follow_joint_trajectory" .

**Comment by [xioaheqiufeng](https://answers.ros.org/users/49412/xioaheqiufeng/) on 2019-11-15**:
Hello, I have some questions. I have established two ur10 configuration files in moveit, but I can't control two ur robots at the same time. Do you control the two robots through one robot controller or through the controller respectively? If not, how do you inform the two robots to perform tasks? Can you tell me? Thank you very much